# Drop shadow around all the four sides of an EditText in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

As far as my knowledge aids me, there isn't any property to drop shadow around an EditText field, that can be set in the layout file. I searched for the problem and found solution that I've to provide a custom background xml drawable.

My drawable/background_with_shadow looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-lis xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and I'm setting this property for my `LinearLayout` which contains an `EditText`

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">
<EditText>
.
.
</EditText>
<LinearLayout>
```

However it just drops the shadow around the bottom and bottom corners.
How would I do it for all the four sides and corners?

I'm trying to achieve this:
[image]

Comment: try making background to null. like this  `android:background="@null"`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention in my question, but I need white backround with my `EditText` and shadow around it @Jolson

Comment: using 9 patch would be a good option here.

Comment: what kindda 9 patch do I need? @AshishRanjan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some better ways to get shadow around your edit text without using `layer-list` :

**#1**

Wrap your `EditText` in a `CardView` like this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="7dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/msg_box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:hint="Write a message"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:textColorHint="#c7c7c7"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**OUTPUT** :

[image: Shadow using CardView]

## 2

Use a 9 patch as the background of your `EditText` :

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msg_box"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:lines="5"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Enter your complaint..."
        android:textColorHint="#a7a7a7"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: 9patch shadow]

Read more about 9patch [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html).

[Here](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/)'s a great online tool to generate 9 patch shadow.

Comment: you need a patch image of the shadow that you want to add around all the four sides of your edittext.

Comment: check the last link to get a 9 patch image by adjusting the shadow using blur option and set the height and width to some small value like 10, and corner radius to 0.

Comment: there's a problem though. I wanted my `EditText`'s background to be white but now its transparent @Ashish Ranjan

Comment: either wrap the `TextView` in a layout(`RelativeLayout`) and set the layout's background color to white **or** a much simpler way is to enable the fill color in the above link and select white

Answer (score 7):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <!-- set the shadow color here -->
            <stroke
                android:width="2.5dp"
                android:color="@color/darker_gray" />

            <!-- setting the thickness of shadow (positive value will give shadow on that side) -->

            <!--Set shadow width as per your requirement -->
            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="0.5dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="0.5dp" />

            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--White Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#fff" />  
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Set this layout as your LinearLayout background.**

Comment: This works great. Also the comments made it easiest to understand.
How can I make the borders look like shadow? @Kunu

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you trying to achieve?

Comment: Edited my question and added screenshot @Kunu

Comment: Just use my layout as background for your LinearLayout and make your Edittext background transparent.

Comment: can I achieve this without wrapping my `EditText` in a `LinearLayout`?